# Force HTML DOCTYPE Declaration

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Im running sharepoint 2007 and im adding the following html doctype declaration to the first few lines of the master page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang=”en”>
```

When i reload the site in IE and press f-12 im realizing that the browser is not recognizing the declaration. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this problem. The reason i need to add this is for a CSS dropdown menu to work properly.

I thought i had this problem solved but i didnt.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 3):

If this is required to run your drop down menu you should better look for something else because this is a HTML5 declaration that might use CSS 3 features. This can completely break the SharePoint Functions especially in SharePoint 2007 and you also need to consider that all user that access your SharePoint must have at least IE9.

You might end up in a working drop down but the rest of SharePoint won't work anymore.

A better solution for you might be to look for some DropDowns based on jquery.

SharePoint 2007 is built only for the use of XHTML and not HTML5 or HTML4.

Comment: does sharepoint 2007 natively support jQuery or would i have to upload the jquery .js file somewhere onto the server?

Comment: You could embed it in the master page using the CND Location. Therefor you don't have to upload any file to sharepoint. For example:
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`